# Magento: Category Management and iframe not refresh

Tags: javascript, magento, iframe, categories

I have Magento 1.9.1. and I am in Category Management.
When I click on a child (category) or a node (sub-category) in the tree, the right column, with the iframe and the fileds, doesn't refresh automatically. I see the circle with the "loading" but after the page doesn't change. 
I have to refresh manually the browser page to see the fields with the right content.

What is the event/script that updates the content of the iframe on click?
What is a best tool/plugin to check this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I found the event. When I click it recall ".../index.php/admin/catalog_category/edit/key/41dfcdyrr5h79902ea/id/3578/?isAjax=true" but the reply of script is "{"content":null,"messages":""}". It is wrong. The right reply could be: "{"content":"\n<div class=\"content-header\">\n   ecc..."